# Sitecore poweshell to find list all rendering on page in specific language

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell

Sitecore poweshell to find list of all rendering on page in specific language and extract in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is to find all renderings on a page associated with the FinalLayout. Pass the language as "en".

```
write-host 'Running script...'
Set-Location master:\content
$pages = get-item master:\content\home | get-childitem -Recurse -Language "en"
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$Results = @();
$DataPath = "C:\MySite\ComponentsInUse.csv"

foreach($page in $pages){

$renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $page -Device $device -FinalLayout

foreach($rendering in $renderings){

    if($rendering.ItemID -ne $null)
    {
        $renderingItem = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.ItemID
        if($renderingItem -ne $null)
        {
            $Properties = @{
                RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
            }

            $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
        }
    }

}
}

$Results | Select-Object RenderingItemName,RenderingItemID,RenderingItemPath,UsedOnPage,UsedOnPageID,UsedOnPagePath | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $DataPath

write-host 'Script ended'
```

For reference check -
https://codebuildplay.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/sitecore-powershell-how-to-create-a-list-of-renderings-in-use/
https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/presentation/get-rendering
https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items/item-renderings

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the precise answer by Gaurav Agrawal,
If you plan to run this on non-local environments, you can display list in interactive modal and download it yourself.

[image]

Just use this line,

```
$Results | Show-ListView
```

instead of

```
$Results | Select-Object RenderingItemName,RenderingItemID,RenderingItemPath,UsedOnPage,UsedOnPageID,UsedOnPagePath | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $DataPath
```